# Teamcity and batch file

Tags: batch-file, teamcity

I am currently trying to pull a `powershell` script that resides in the project sub folder.  When my `batch` file runs it tries to locate the file path within the project, but am doing so without any success.

I first tried to pass the subfolder directly as it is in Teamcity:

```
set file = "subFolder\myPowershell.ps1"
```

My second attempt I tried to call:

```
set file = %~dp0"subFolder\myPowershell.ps1"
```

Then I tried:

```
set file = %cd%"subFolder\myPowershell.ps1"
```

With still no success.  How can I get the path to this `powershell` script within the `Teamcity` project folder from a `batch` file?

Comment: `%~dp0"subFolder\myPowershell.ps1"` Seems to me the quotes are not properly located. Have you tried `"%~dp0subFolder\myPowershell.ps1"`?

Comment: `set "file=%~dp0subFolder\myPowershell.ps1"` to get the pure path into variable `file` without the surrounding quotes...

Comment: @Laf Yes, I tried to include  `%~dp0` in the quotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I have to prefix the file directory with `%1` and teamcity picked it right up.

```
set file="%1\subFolder\myPowershell.ps1"
```

Thanks everyone for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do:

```bat
set file="%~dp0project sub folder\myPowershell.ps1"
```

***note***: `%~dp0` already contains a trailing back slash so an additional one isn't required. You will also note that there is no space either side of the **`=`** in the `set` command this is also essential.

Comment: This didn't work.  I removed all the spaces and still nothing.

Comment: As the code I have posted is completely correct, the issue is with the information you are providing to us. Please therefore post the rest of the script complete with the tree showing your files/folder structure.

Comment: Yes, it does work but with teamcity it doesn't.  Says it can't find the file.

Comment: Why not update the question using the Edit facility and provide the rest of the information then. I've provided a solution for the only part I can because it is the only part for which you've given me sufficient information.